# How can I build a JSON object-key from string

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

In a AngularJS environment I've got two JSON objects like the following:

```
var rowData = {
     fields: {
         Id: 1234,
         Code: xyz
     }
};
var access = {
    0: "fields['Id']"
}
```

now I want to access the value of rowData.fields['Id'] generic by evaluating the value of access[0].

I tried:

```
var result = rowData.access[0]
```

which of course does not work. Problem seems to be that the value of `access[0]` is a string.

How do I convert this to being usable in this given scenario?

Comment: I'll add this as a comment as I'm sure there must be a better way to do it... `eval("rowData." + access[0]);`

Comment: This is an unusual construct. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @ken4z: "fields['Id']" is the kind of structure ng-grid uses to render it's grid. Im trying to use this data-structure to build a separate card-view, which can be used for mobile environments. You get the data unsorted and have to sort it by a structure defined in a column-json. This is why it's gettin kind of acrobatic in here... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want this in the context of Angular, you can utilize the `$parse` service ([ref](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24parse)):

```
var getter = $parse(access[0]);
var result = getter(rowData);
```